# Что означает модификатор final в полях классов?

Tags: java, final

Я заметил, что профессиональные разработчики нередко объявляют поля классов в джаве как final, например:

```
@Component
public class LinkResolver implements GraphQLResolver<Link> {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public LinkResolver(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public User postedBy(Link link) {
        if (link.getUserId() == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return userRepository.findById(link.getUserId());
    }
}
```

Для чего это делается? Я видел, как в проекте `final` объявляются не только поля сервисов и репозиториев, но и поля дата-классов. Расскажите об этом больше, пожалуйста.

Comment: Чтобы можно было только один раз инициализировать переменную, например только в конструкторе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Многа букав:** По-умолчанию ставятся максимальные ограничения. Снимать ограничение (final) с поля имеет смысл только если на это есть причина (поле изменяется).

С помощью `final` отмечаются поля, которые инициализируются только один раз. Отмечать такое поле как `final` технически необязательно, но если этого не сделать, то:

- останется возможность ошибки: разработчик опечатается и переприсвоит значение;
- при чтении кода возникнут вопросы: «Где это поле изменяется? И как это повлияет на остальной код?». Модификатор `final` говорит разработчику что лишние сценарии рассматривать не требуется.

Вообще значительная часть программирования это расстановка ограничений. Чем меньше операций можно выполнить с кодом — тем легче о нем рассуждать — тем проще проверить его правильность. Поэтому разработчики стараются устанавливать для полей/переменных максимально жесткие ограничения, чтобы снизить количество возможных сценариев их использования.

По аналогичной причине поля, которые не используются вне класса, объявляются как `private`. Поле с доступом по-умолчанию оставит лишние сценарии использования и, вместе с ними, простор для ошибок и вопросов («Из какого класса к нему идет обращение и зачем?»).

Многие IDE и средства анализа кода (например, [PMD](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_java_codestyle.html#localvariablecouldbefinal)) отслеживают поля и переменные, которые могут быть отмечены как `final` и выдают соответствующие предупреждения.

На практике поля, как важную часть классов, везде где возможно отмечают как final. На локальных переменных и аргументах методов же обычно «экономят», т.к. срок жизни у них короче и риск побочных эффектов меньше. Для них наоборот используют final только там где это явно необходимо (использование в анонимных классах). Например, в Вашем коде аргументы конструктора (`userRepository`) и метода (`link`) могли бы быть отмечены как `final`, но не отмечены для простоты кода.

Answer (score 10):

1. Удобно чисто визуально. Если видишь, что переменная `final`, то точно знаешь, что она не будет меняться.
2. Без `final` никак, если ты локальную переменную собираешься использовать в анонимных классах/замыканиях.
3. `final` - это подсказка компилятору. Если он видит финальные поля, то может произвести определённые оптимизации кода.

Comment: А final, примененное к полям, может иметь какое-то значение при наследовании?

Comment: @typemoon принципиальной нет. Поля всё также остаются неизменяемыми.

Comment: в ответе кроется одно коварство, некоторые новички путают final с иммутабельностью...

Comment: 4. final-поля безопасно публикуются в многопоточном окружении

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ещё про рефлексию можно написать )

Comment: что она не будет меняться  => ссылка на нее не будет меняться

Answer (score 0):

Модификатор `final` на полях, говорит о том, что данное поле, является окончательным, что его нельзя изменить.
Часто финальными в **Java** объявляются константы, поля значения которых неизменяемые.
Так же `final` можно объявлять целый классы, или же методы.

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю к предыдущим ответам, что `final` дает потокобезопасность в многопоточном коде. Представим, что в одном потоке мы создаем наш объект, а другой поток тут же пытается его прочитать. Поля, помеченные `final`, не будут доступны ни одному из потоков до тех пор, пока целиком не будут проинициализированы.